# password in URL in spring security oauth2 token endpoint

Tags: spring-security, passwords, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring security oauth2 password grant for authenticating users with clientid/client secrets. The issue that I am facing is that the endpoint takes the password as a query parameter. This gets logged in the access logs for the server on which this service will be running. I have a wrapper over the endpoint which is internally calling the token endpoint using HTTP.

I have no control on the server and will not be able to mask password or disable access logs.

Is there any way of directly invoking the underlying endpoint controller method itself without using the REST endpoint for doing this or some other way in which the password does not need to be sent by the query parameters?

Comment: My first impression is: you have done something wrong in your application regarding the OAuth2 flow. Do the authorization server behaves correct according to the OAuth2 specification? Is it a home grown implementation or a commercial product or Spring Security OAuth2? What have you done in your application regarding OAuth2? Please show us your implementation otherwise nobody can really help you. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a wrapper service for authentication which takes username, password, clientid and client_secret and calls spring token endpoint to authenticate. the spring token endpoint is called as /oauth/token?username=name&password=password&grant_type=password. I pass authorization header containing basic authentication with base64 encoded client id and secret. I dont think the issue is in my application. I am talking about the spring oauth endpoint itself. It takes the username, password, grant_type as URL parameters and those are logged in access logs.

Answer (score 1):

token endpoint accepts to get the parameters with POST method and you can then supply the content-type header as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the parameters as x-www-form-urlencoded params